# Does extraction workers in google bigquery save the data into Columnar Storage follows a FIFO pattern?

Tags: google-bigquery

As I understand from [bigquery streaming insert lifecycle](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/06/life-of-a-bigquery-streaming-insert)  also shown in the image below. The data goes through streaming buffer before it is available in the **Columnar Storage**. The work of processing the data is done by the **Extraction Workers**.

However, in the documentation, it is not mentioned how the extraction workers process the data. Do they follow a random order for processing or it is FIFO processing?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The streaming buffer is a queue, and the extraction worker processes rows in order. The extraction workers take from the queue either when it reaches a certain volume of data or when a certain amount of time has elapsed in order to write sufficiently large chunks of data to managed storage. The underlying storage format in BigQuery is [Capacitor](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/04/inside-capacitor-bigquerys-next-generation-columnar-storage-format), which reorders rows as it is persisting them to disk and performs a variety of other optimizations as well.

Comment: How much time must elapse before it writes the contents of the buffer to managed storage?